# Are those matrices congruent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{array}\right),
> B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&0 \\ 0&2 \end{array}\right), C =
>  \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&0 \\ 0&4 \end{array}\right)$$
>
> Are those matrices congruent
>
> - above $\mathbb{R}$?
> - above $\mathbb{C}$?
> - above $\mathbb{Q}$?

So basically I've evaluated:
$\det (1) = 1, \det \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{array}\right) = -1$. hence, $A$ is congruent to $\text{Diag}(1,-1)$.

In the same way, $B, C$ are congruent to $\text{Diag}(1,1)$.

Hence, $B$ and $C$ are congruence but, $A$ isn't congruent to $B,C$

This evaluation is above $\mathbb{R}$, but it's also applied to the extended field, $\mathbb{C}$. Isn't it?

Finally, what sohuld I do for $F=\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I think you are using the word, "congruence", in a non-standard way. What do you mean when you say, matrix $D$ is congruence to matrix $E$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence

Comment: Ah, so you are using "congruence" where everyone else uses "congruent". You might want to edit your question, to bring it into line with standard usage.

Comment: Note that $\det(P^tAP)=\det A(\det P)^2$. That should tell you something about what happens over the rationals.

Comment: 1) The law of inertia is valid for $\mathbb{C}$ too. 2)$A$ is not congruent to others over $\mathbb{R}$, hence, not congruent over any sub-field. 3) Use the fact that $S^TBS=C$ for non-rational $S=\left[\matrix{1 & 0\\0 & \sqrt{2}}\right]$ to prove that there cannot exist a rational transformation. P.S. The hint from @GerryMyerson is even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{R}$ $B$ is congruent to $C$ and as you said above $A$ is not congruent to $B$ and $C$ since the signature of $A$ is $(1,1,0)$ ad the signature of $B,C$ is $(2,0,0)$.

Over $\mathbb{C}$ the situation is quite different. Infact $A$ is equivalent to $B$ and $C$; clearly $B$ is still equivalent to $C$ since real coefficient are also complex coefficient and so the congruence matrix is the same of the case above.

Take 
$$P=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&i\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$ so $B=PA\text{}^tP$.

If we call $Q$ the matrix that realize the congruence in the real case we also have $C=QB\text{}^tQ=QPA\text{}^tP\text{}^tQ$.

In the rational case the congruence matrix need to have all coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ and you can easily see (using the determinant properties) that there are no matrix that realize the congruence between every couple of matrix above.

Answer (score 1):

We consider the COMPLEX case.

Proposition. if $A,B$ are invertible and symmetric complex matrices , then they are congruent

Proof. We use a pretty result due to Horn and Sergeichuk.

Let $U,V\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then, they are congruent iff $U^{-T}U$ and $V^{-T}V$ are similar.

That's all folk.